# Prevent collision/overlap of ties in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond, engraving, ties

Running the input

```
\score {
  \relative c' {
    <c d f g b c>4~
    4
  }
  \layout {
    \context {
      \Score
      \override SpacingSpanner.base-shortest-duration = #(ly:make-moment 1/16)
    }
  }
}
```

through Lilypond results in the following output:

[image: Lilypond's interpretation of the above excerpt]

The ties between the Bs and the Gs cross over each other. What's the best way to fix this (preferably automatically)?

Comment: The ties are *supposed to* cross over each other (at least they default to doing so in Musescore, and I think this crossing looks fine). I recommend *not* trying to "fix this".

Comment: @Dekkadeci I'm interested in an example of this in published music or a reference that sanctions such ties—I'm not trying to be argumentative, but I've never seen it before, which is why I made this post in the first place. Maybe I overreacted by implying it was an actual problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is expected output or not. At any rate, you can override the default placement using the explicit direction specifiers `^` and `_`. In this case, you need to write the `~` on each note of the chord so you can change its direction individually. For example:

```
\version "2.22.1"

\relative c' {
  <c d f g b c>1~
  q
  <c_~ d_~ f_~ g^~ b^~ c^~>
  q
}
```

This syntax is explained here:

https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/direction-and-placement.html